# cronjob at 12 am USA time nodejs

Tags: node.js, cron

I am implementing a **cron job** which was running at hours.

```
let cron= require('node-cron');
 cron.schedule('0 0-23 * * *', ()=> {
   cronjob.deletdOldFiles();
 });
```

and it is working fine. but now the solution I want is to call **cron job at every 12am according to USA timezone** Timezone is compulsory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
let cron = require('node-cron')
 
cron.schedule('0 0-23 * * *', () => {
    cronjob.deletdOldFiles()
  },
  { 
    timezone: 'America/Chicago'
  }
);
```

Comment: what if I want timezone of 'America/Washington'

Comment: Check the list of available timezones here, and check the closest to Washington: https://gist.github.com/diogocapela/12c6617fc87607d11fd62d2a4f42b02a